# Oracle Service Bus - Application Server & JMS Support

Tags: oracle, weblogic-10.x, osb

Is Oracle Service Bus supported by any application server in the backend - for eg: weblogic application server? Or does it have its own implementation of application server?

Tibco has something called EMS which is its implementation of JMS spec. Does OSB have its own implementation of JMS? Or does it utilize the capabilities of any application server which it is integrated with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSB runs on Weblogic and it is the only suppoorted application server. Some other fussion Middleware products can run on WebShpere. Details can be found in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/downloads/fmw-11gr1certmatrix.xls

OSB don't have its own JMS implementation. It can use any standard JMS (e.g. one shipped with Weblogic). It has also adapters for IBM WebSphere MQ.